# How to handle customRole in serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework

I would like to have different roles for different stages in serverless.

*Example for stage 'dev'  I have roleA-dev and for stage 'prod' the role is roleA-prod*

What is best way to handle this kind of situation in serverless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to update `customRole` within `s-function.json` to include the `${stage}` variable.

```
"customRole": "RoleA-${stage}"
```

Unfortunately, this functionality is currently incomplete in the released version of Serverless, but is expected to be available in v0.5. A [GitHub issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/681) has been opened that includes this specific functionality.

**20160304 Update:**
Serverless v0.5 has now been released for beta testing. You can install it using the following command:

```
npm install git://github.com/serverless/serverless#v0.5 -g
```